# Image load with jQuery without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want http://jsfiddle.net/tv0evg7d/1/ to implement in my website. I copied the codes so that I can test whether its working or not. But when I click show on my website the image is not loaded as its working in the Fiddle. jQuery library is loaded from the header file which is included in the page. The library is named as `jquery.min.js`. Everything seems to be fine but I am not getting why its not working. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Markup from fiddle:

```
<input id="inputBox" value="http://www.clusterflock.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/owl-in-a-hat.jpg"/>
<button id="loadImage">Show</button>
<br/>
<img id="image" src="" alt="No image loaded"/>
```

Code

```
$("#loadImage").on('click', function(){
    $("#image").attr("src", $("#inputBox").val());
});
```

My script:

```
<script>
$("#loadImage").click(function(){
    $("#image").attr("src", $("#inputBox").val());
});
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="main-container height-auto" style="width: 20%">
    <?php include'side-menu.php'; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="main-container height-auto main-cont-adjust">
    <div class="container-title">
      <h3>Banner Ads on <?php echo $sf['si_name']; ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="member-index-container" align="right">
      <div class="mi-banner" style="margin-left: 0"><img src="images/adv-here2.png"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php echo $msg; ?>
    <div class="ads-box">
      <table class="table-list">
        <!--form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"-->
        <tr>
          <th class="left-align">Banner URL</th>
          <td class="left-align"><input type="text" name="burl" class="ad-field" required value="<?php echo $burl; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="left-align">Target URL</th>
          <td class="left-align"><input type="text" name="turl" class="ad-field" required value="<?php echo $turl; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="left-align">Duration</th>
          <td class="left-align"><select name="bprice" class="select-field" required>
              <?php while($bpf = $bpq->fetch()){ extract($bpf); ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $bp_id; ?>"><?php echo $bp_days; if($bp_days > 1){ echo " days at $"; }else{ echo " day at $"; } echo $bp_amount; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="left-align">Wallet Balance: $<?php echo $pc_bal; ?></th>
          <th align="right"><input type="submit" name="buy_ad" value="Pay with Wallet" class="login-btn btn btn-black" style="width: 170px"></th>
        </tr>
        </form>

      </table>
    </div>
    <input id="inputBox" value=""/>
    <button id="loadImage">Show</button>
    <br/>
    <img id="image" src="" alt="No image loaded" />
    <div class="container-title">
      <h4>Ad Preview - This is how your Ad will look like</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="mi-banner" style="margin-left: 0; border: 1px solid #ddd;">
      <!--img src="" id="image" alt="Type or Paste banner URL and click on CHECK"-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code works, but the url is broken. Use another image and it will show.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tv0evg7d/4/

Comment: code works on fiddle.. not on my website.. i want it to work on my website... same code is what i copied but its not working. please help.

Comment: So you should show us your whole html code and not an environment where everything is set up clean.

Comment: question updated. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loadImage").on('click', function() {
    $("#image").attr("src", $("#inputBox").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputBox" value="http://publicador.tvcultura.com.br/upload/tvcultura/programas/programa-imagem-som.jpg"/>
<button id="loadImage">Show</button>
<br/>
<img id="image" src="" alt="No image loaded"/>
```

Comment: i do not have problem with that URL. That's a simple thing to notice. The problem is that the code works on fiddle.. not on my website.. i want it to work on my website... same code is what i copied but its not working. please help.

Comment: your jquery version in website?

Comment: jQuery v1.12.0 which in in header.php page and header.php is included in this page.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you function with `$(document).ready(function() {..});`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loadImage").on('click', function() {
    $("#image").attr("src", $("#inputBox").val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment "and header.php is included in this page" so basically, this code attempts to run prior to jQuery being included. That appears to be your real issue here. You should instead include jQuery on the page and then on the header only load it if it is not already present

There are many posts you can find on how to do that last part.